# Chaincode can be listed by cli container, but doesn't exist in peer container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I deployed a Fabric network with two organizations: org1 and org2.Each organization has two peers.

Then I installed a chaincode on peer0.org1 via peer0.org1 cli container, and then I checked it to see if the chaincode was also installed in the same org's another peer: peer1.org1. I checked via peer1.org1 cli container, and the answer was yes. The screenshot is below:
[image]

But when I entered the peer1.org1 peer container, I found that there is no chaincode under folder /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/. The screenshot is below:
[image]
The result of cli query through peer1.org1 cli is not consistent with the actual result in the peer1.org1 container. Why? Is this by design? Thanks very much.

Comment: hmm, can you please run a transaction and see if that changes the container directory?

Comment: I have already run several transaction, and there is still nothing under peer1.org1 /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/. A peer's cli command "peer chaincode list --installed" can't directly reflect the chaincode's real installation status on the peer. So I want to confirm what is the cause? Is this by design?

Comment: Can you please check CORE_PEER_ADDRESS environment variable on peer1.org1?

Comment: Just now I entered peer1.org1 container bash and checked that CORE_PEER_ADDRESS environment variable on peer1.org1 is "peer1.org1.yingzi.com:7051". Note that in my Fabric network, peer0.org1 and peer1.org1 are installed on the same server in the way of docker, so in order to  avoid port conflict, I set 8051:7051,8052:7052,8053:7053 port mapping in docker-compose yaml file for peer1.org1. But I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: @LinCorey So I'm confused, you said you've installed chaincode on peer0.org1, hence you should not be able to see it installed on peer1.org1 file system which the actual experience you see. However, that confuses me is that you do able to see it while running "peer chaincode list --installed" on peer1.org1.

Comment: Yes, this also confused me. Although I started peer0.org1 and peer1.org1 on the same server, they are running in separate docker containers and isolated from each other, so I think they should not affect each other.